# Use monte carlo simulation to predict Y variable (linear regression) of a given dataset, and estimate the parameter coefficients

Tags: r, simulation, monte-carlo

It's my first time learning Monte carlo simulation, I have been given a task to predict the average Y variable (dependent variable) using a given dataset and to estimate the values of the
parameter coefficients and standard errors of the coefficients of the linear regression model.

Now, I've done the linear model and extracted the estimated values of the parameter coefficients, but I don't know what to do afterwards to predict an average value for my Y variable using montecarlo simulation.

```r
model1 <- lm(Yvar ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4, data = dataset)
sum_model <- summary(model1)

names(sum_model)
sum_model$coefficients
model_table <- as.data.frame(sum_model$coefficients)
View(model_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually Monte Carlo simulations refer to parametric simulations based on normal distribution. There are different ways to apply Monte Carlo simulations to linear regression. The first and the most straightforward procedure is the following:

1. Based on the observations, estimate the parameters of the linear model and the residuals $\hat{\varepsilon}$;
2. Given some Goodness of Fit test (Kolmogorov–Smirnov, Cramér–von Mises or Anderson-Darling for example) evaluate the fitting of the normal distribution. If the fitting is poor, you may consider another distribution like Student-$t$;
3. Sample $\varepsilon^*$ based on the distribution of the previous point;
4. Based on the residuals simulated at the previous point and on the parameter estimates from the first point, calculate the simulated fitted values $\hat{Y}^*$
5. Repeat the procedure $B$ times and every time compute the average of the simulated fitted values;

If you want to employ Monte Carlo simulations for getting also coefficients confidence intervals and standard errors the procedure is still valid but after point 4. you estimated a new set of parameters considering the simulated fitted values as dependent variable.